# Best packages for theme management

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

What are the best software packages in Ubuntu that give me themes management (installing, removing , editing ) in a easy way By GUI ?

Comment: Four apps come to mind: Ubuntu Tweak, MyUnity, Advanced Settings, and Unsettings. The first three are available in the Ubuntu Software Center. I don't think the fourth is. I think they'll do part of what you want in that you'll be able to switch themes. I don't know about installing and removing. And I don't think editing is possible. That has to be done by editing various files (such as .rc, .ini, .css). There's Gnome Color Chooser for gtk2 apps that gives you a GUI to change various aspects.

Comment: @vasa1 - i dont think `Ubuntu tweak` is available in Ubuntu Software center , but via PPA :)

Comment: @tijybba, did you search for "tweak" and then click on "technical items" at the bottom left? Or maybe it's showing for me because I did install it from a ppa some months while ago and USC is reflecting that?

Comment: It looks like USC does reflect apps that have been installed via ppas. I can see Google Chrome and I installed that via ppa too. And we all know that Chrome isn't part of the USC by default :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.**Ubuntu Tweak 0.7**

[image]

**Installation**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

2.**MyUnity**

[image]

**Installation**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myunity/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install myunity
```

3.**Gnome Tweak Tool**

[image]

**Installation**

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Enjoy!